# textbox wpf to right

Tags: wpf, textbox, width

I have canvas with user control (border with textbox). when I put sth I want to resize textbox with border from left to right side. I have event textBox_TextChanged, and there I set new border width from textbox width.

[please look at image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykNWZ.png)

Comment: You should just set the horizontal alignment of the textbox to right and set the width property to auto.

Comment: @CoskunOzogul Besides that it isn't what was asked for, a Canvas parent would ignore that.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your issue when asking  a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @CoskunOzogul is the same :( I forgot write, this border with textbox is a user control

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the border+textbox to expand to the left as you type? Try to set the `Canvas.Right` to position your `Border`:

```
    <Canvas Width="300" Height="200">
        <Border Canvas.Top="10"
                Canvas.Right="50"
                BorderBrush="Orange"
                BorderThickness="2">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
```

Obviously, `Title` above is the viewmodel's property.